# Retrieve Data from Windows Azure Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, odata, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

How do I query my Windows Azure Storage such as:

```
(SELECT Name FROM User WEHRE DeviceID = App.Current.DeviceID)
```

**Tried this, didn't seem to work**

```
var Name = await App.MobileService.GetTable<User>()
    .Select(User => User.Name)
    .Where(User => User.DeviceID == App.Current.DeviceID);
```

**But I could query the table based on the id**

```
 var Name = await App.MobileService.GetTable<User>().LookupAsync(id);
```

Is there a similar method to query the table based on string(eg. phone DeviceID) instead of an integer id?

**User Class**

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DeviceID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you ToString the LinqQuery?  I believe that is the easiest way to find the OData query underneath.  Since SQL azure doesn't apply, I'll retag this OData.

Comment: what do you mean by ToString the LinqQuery? What I want to do is to select the name from the user table based on the device id. But right now, lookup async only works with integer id and i do not know of another way to retrieve data based on a string

Comment: At a low level, Azure storage works using REST commands.  I should rephrase, you're not using Linq but the SDK is translating them into a REST string.  To assist in debugging your solution look for a method that allows you to output a string (.ToString()) or (.ToAzureString()) at the end of the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the `Where` method is still a *query* object, it isn't the object itself yet. You need to call one of the `ToListAsync` or `ToEnumerableAsync` to actually make the request:

```
var Name = (await App.MobileService.GetTable<User>()
    .Where(User => User.DeviceID == App.Current.DeviceID)
    .Select(User => User.Name)
    .ToEnumerableAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I tried your method but there is an error with the User.DeviceID, it says that string does not contain a definition for DeviceID and no extension method DeviceID can be found

Comment: I had a problem with the order of the statements, fixed now. The `Where` clause should come before the `Select`.